# how read text file in R, that has different format every few rows

Tags: r

can you guys suggest how i can read a text file with these contents/type into a table? eventually i will push table into plot. I tried multiple combinations of 
averages<-read.able("name.txt",header=T,sep="") and get this message:

**Error in read.table("name.txt", header = T, sep = "") : 
  more columns than column names**

I need to be able to keep [[1]], [[2]], [[3]], [[4]] results and distinguish them separately in the table or data frame for plotting later. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
> dput(ll)
c("[[1]]", "Time Queue_Size", "1  0.00000000          0", "2  0.01463509          1", 
"3  0.18473331          0", "4  0.70555473          1", "5  1.10322362          0", 
"6  2.24972346          1", "7  2.32344665          0", "8  3.30621739          1", 
"9  3.37728921          2", "10 3.47074298          1", "11 3.75560929          0", 
"12 4.56816309          1", "", "[[2]]", "        Time Queue_Size", 
"1  0.0000000          0", "2  0.1080389          1", "3  0.5729134          0", 
"4  1.0917759          1", "5  1.1280721          0", "6  1.3647759          1", 
"7  1.9137004          0", "8  3.1164888          1", "9  3.1500754          0", 
"10 3.2951701          1", "11 3.9362245          0", "12 4.7629641          1", 
"", "[[3]]", "        Time Queue_Size", "1  0.0000000          0", 
"2  0.2151396          1", "3  0.5810463          0", "4  1.2669130          1", 
"5  1.2694239          0", "6  1.2890854          1", "7  1.7050347          0", 
"8  2.3904563          1", "9  2.6800687          2", "10 2.7654936          3", 
"11 2.9624973          4", "12 2.9652142          3", "13 3.0096070          4", 
"14 3.1811061          3", "15 3.5783809          2", "16 3.6793138          1", 
"17 3.9339087          0", "18 4.5799301          1", "", "[[4]]", 
"        Time Queue_Size", "1  0.0000000          0", "2  0.1200693          1", 
"3  0.3663455          2", "4  0.5931517          1", "5  0.8235883          2", 
"6  0.8590099          1", "7  0.9474114          0", "8  1.1327633          1", 
"9  1.2933192          0", "10 1.8779916          1", "11 2.2328193          0", 
"12 2.7430489          1", "13 2.8380578          2", "14 2.8465716          3", 
"15 3.0760839          4", "16 3.4489915          5", "17 3.8352777          4", 
"18 4.2612698          5")
```

ll looks like

```
[[1]]
Time Queue_Size
1  0.00000000          0
2  0.01463509          1
3  0.18473331          0
4  0.70555473          1
5  1.10322362          0
6  2.24972346          1
7  2.32344665          0
8  3.30621739          1
9  3.37728921          2
10 3.47074298          1
11 3.75560929          0
12 4.56816309          1

[[2]]
        Time Queue_Size
1  0.0000000          0
2  0.1080389          1
3  0.5729134          0
4  1.0917759          1
5  1.1280721          0
6  1.3647759          1
7  1.9137004          0
8  3.1164888          1
9  3.1500754          0
10 3.2951701          1
11 3.9362245          0
12 4.7629641          1

[[3]]
        Time Queue_Size
1  0.0000000          0
2  0.2151396          1
3  0.5810463          0
4  1.2669130          1
5  1.2694239          0
6  1.2890854          1
7  1.7050347          0
8  2.3904563          1
9  2.6800687          2
10 2.7654936          3
11 2.9624973          4
12 2.9652142          3
13 3.0096070          4
14 3.1811061          3
15 3.5783809          2
16 3.6793138          1
17 3.9339087          0
18 4.5799301          1

[[4]]
        Time Queue_Size
1  0.0000000          0
2  0.1200693          1
3  0.3663455          2
4  0.5931517          1
5  0.8235883          2
6  0.8590099          1
7  0.9474114          0
8  1.1327633          1
9  1.2933192          0
10 1.8779916          1
11 2.2328193          0
12 2.7430489          1
13 2.8380578          2
14 2.8465716          3
15 3.0760839          4
16 3.4489915          5
17 3.8352777          4
18 4.2612698          5
```

Comment: why don't you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: Is that literally what your input file looks like with the `[[#]]` values and the repeated headers in there?

Comment: Isn't this already a list?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `readLines` to read your file. Then you can split the lines using a regular expressions. Finally, you read each part using `read.table(text=…)`

```
ll <- readLines('filename.txt')
lapply(split(ll,cumsum(grepl('[[',ll,fixed=TRUE))),
         function(x)read.table(text=x[-1],header=T))
```

#### EDIT  explanation of the idea

The use of `cumsum` is a classic way to convert a logical vector to integer vector (used here to split the list). Indeed, the `grepl` creates a logical vector that is converted to a split vector used by `split` function. An example:

```
cumsum(c(T,F,F,T,F))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2
```

Then You can use the result to split a vector :

```
split(1:5,cumsum(c(T,F,F,T,F)))

$`1`
[1] 1 2 3

$`2`
[1] 4 5
```

Comment: Nice. What exactly is cumsum doing in this case?

Comment: @PauloCardoso I add a little explanation.

Comment: Thank you! Honestly this is the first time i see cumsum used in this context.